# TightVNC change passwords from cmd

Tags: vnc, vnc-server

I looking for possibility to change every password in TightVNC from command line.
Every hosts have Windows 10, so I wanna create bat script to change Admin and Primary passwords.

Answer (score 2):

It can look like this:

```
tvnserver.exe -stop
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\TightVNC\Server" /v Password /t REG_BINARY /d F0E43164F6C2E373 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\TightVNC\Server" /v UseVncAuthentication /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 /f
tvnserver.exe -start
```

Comment: what is F0E43164F6C2E373 representing here?

Comment: @Firesh that's the password `12345678` encrypted using a hardcoded DES key (which is hardcoded in the TightVNC source code). Easiest approach may be to use TightVNC config tool to set the password to what you want, then copy the encrypted value from the registry, then you can set it using the command line on another machine.

Comment: @SimonKissane - thank you for the explanation! appreciate it.